# How to execute test cases from multiple classes with priority using Testng in Selenium

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-annotation-test

I have following requirement
I have 3 different classes
Class A
Class B
Class C
in all three classes there are multiple test cases which runs on 3 different URLs
Class A
TC1
Class B
TC2
TC4
Class C
TC3

I want to run the TCs in following sequence
TC1
TC2
TC3
TC4

How can i do that?
I tried with Priority which is not working with multiple classes
Following is my testng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="main.java.utils.SuiteListner" />
    </listeners>
    
    <test name="Test Automation Portal">    
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="url" value="https://v4portal-qa.info/" />
        <classes>
            <class name="main.java.Test.PortalTestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Automation RCAdmin">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="url" value="http://rcadmin-qa.info/auth/index" />
            <classes>
            <class name="main.java.Test.RCAdminTestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Automation Checkout">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="url" value="https://squarefashionqa.test.info/" />
        <classes>
            <class name="main.java.Test.V5CheckoutTestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Automation CRM">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="url" value="https://crm.test.co.uk/login" />
        <classes>
            <class name="main.java.Test.CRMTestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Automation Account">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="url" value="https://accounts.test.co.uk/" />
        <classes>
            <class name="main.java.Test.AccountTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try depends on method to execute test case in sequence. But if any one test case gets failed then it will.skip all next test cases.